# Rails Spree - Round the product value to 2 decimal cases on a item_form.number_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, input, rounding, spree, floating-point-precision

my problem is that on spree on the order page where the input stock number is, this lines of codes:

```
<td class="cart-item-quantity" data-hook="cart_item_quantity">
  Stock.
  <%= item_form.number_field :quantity, :min => 0, :class => "line_item_quantity", :size => 5 %>
</td>
```

Will produce the following html:

```
<td class="cart-item-quantity" data-hook="cart_item_quantity">
Stock.
<input id="quantity_dcm_cart" class="line_item_quantity_dcm"type="number" value="0.7000000000000001" step="0.1" size="5" name="quantity_dcm_cart" min="0">
<input id="order_line_items_attributes_0_quantity" class="line_item_quantity" type="number" hidden="hidden" value="7" size="5" name="order[line_items_attributes][0][quantity]" min="0">
</td>
```

The problem is that value is 0.700000001 and i wanted to have only one decimal cases and be round to 0.7 as the value of that input or the the browser will say the value is not accepted.

Any way that using this spree rails code to achieve this?

Thanks.

P.S.:  Зелёный did a jsfiddle right now where you can easily see what's the problem. Thanks.
https://jsfiddle.net/m2mLg9sr/

Comment: Like here ? https://jsfiddle.net/m2mLg9sr/

Comment: Yes, my problems is that one. The validator won't accept that so i need a way to have only 0,7 on the value.

Comment: so, just make `value='0.7'` and add `disabled` attribute. https://jsfiddle.net/m2mLg9sr/1/ if i right understand

Comment: i could do that if i had direct access to the value but i can't use disabled since that is a stock field the user must have the permission to change it and that value number comes from the rails code which is why i'm having trouble to make it only have one decimal case. Whatever i do i'm not able to change the rails code to add the value only with one decimal.

Comment: sorry, it is unclear for me what you want.

Comment: No problem at all. Your comment is making me already testing some ideias. Let's hope it can fix this. Also your jsfiddle was very good on showing my main problem.